# Can't display/remove registry entry set by malware

Tags: windows, windows-8, windows-registry, malware, unicode

I have a registry entry with strange characters:

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Desktop\Install\{a33ad396-dacb-512c-46ab-10675be7c6b5}\   \...\‮ﯹ๛\{a33ad396-dacb-512c-46ab-10675be7c6b5}\GoogleUpdate.exe" <

"C:\Users\Bart\AppData\Local\Google\Desktop\Install\{a33ad396-dacb-512c-46ab-10675be7c6b5}\dxÙ\" h\.ù[\{a33ad396-dacb-512c-46ab-10675be7c6b5}\GoogleUpdate.exe" >

C:\Users\Bart\AppData\Local\Google\Desktop\Install\{a33ad396-dacb-512c-46ab-10675be7c6b5}\❤≸⋙\Ⱒ☠⍨\‮ﯹ๛\{a33ad396-dacb-512c-46ab-10675be7c6b5}\L
```

It's all about these two characters: ‮ﯹ๛

(Try to copy this to Notepad and see what happens)

Everything that you type behind that character is going from right to left.

Regedit can't read this value and gives this error: `error reading the value's contents` when you open the `Run` subkey. That's why I can't delete this entry at all.

I'm almost sure it's the ZeroAccess malware.

What's going on here?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot modify it because it has reg_none value and you will need a native registry editor to load the hives and then remove it from there. However, you can delete the whole run key and you will be fine. You can find more info regarding this rootkit here http://www.virusresearch.org/zeroaccess-botnet-crippled-but-not-dead/

Answer (score 0):

Not sure which Marlware it is but use RegAssassin, it should be able to delete any registry key.

```
http://www.malwarebytes.org/products/regassassin/
```

As for the virus itself, install Kaspersky Internet Security trial (my favorite and one of the most powerful AV software) and run a scan.

Answer (score 0):

Kaspersky has a free Rootkit Remover tool called TDSSKiller that includes ZeroAccess rootkit removal (which is what you have, I can tell by the signature Unicode reverse-alphabetical folders under Google/Desktop/Install).

http://support.kaspersky.com/us/5350

Also, the http://www.GMER.net tool will let you delete those registry entries.